# mining command-key term explanation

Tags: bfgminer

Could you please explain me the meaning behind the terms and actions of the cmd line like:
bfgminer -o stratum+tcp://stratum.mining.eligius.st:3334 -O YourAddress

and this:
bfgminer -o stratum+tcp://uk1.ghash.io:3333-u username.worker -p YourPasswordHere

Thank you for your time.
Best regards

Comment: Does `bfgminer --help` have anything?

Comment: @StephenM347 thank you. it helped me a little. could you please tell me about using the Intensity (I)-it's range-behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Bfgminer is the mining application, the line with the stratum output is the pool that the miner is configured to use. Your address would be a bitcoin address that you own. The worker name and password would be credentials to access your account at the mining pool although most often the password is not used or is substituted with x.